# Issue with PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Good evening everyone, I'm having issues with my below code, Variable $uname is declared from a http post but for some reason the print out the the err log stays blank where it should show the results of the MySQL query

Field in table is called firstname (no caps)

```
$da= mysqli_query($c,
            "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$uname."'") or  die(mysqli_error($c));


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($da)) {



                error_log("User $Uname:  match.");
                error_log("FN :  ".$row['firstname']."");


            }
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: you are using `$Uname` instead of `$uname` - php variables are case-sensitive

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Also, see prepared statements

Comment: Try setting the username to "bob' OR 1=1"...  I'm sure you'll get at least one result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a message to tell you if no results were found by the query.

Since there can be only one user with a given username (I assume), you don't need a `while` loop. Just fetch that one row.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($da));
if ($row) {
    error_log("User $uname:  match.");
    error_log("FN :  ".$row['firstname']."");
} else {
    error_log("User $uname: no match.");
}
```

You also had a typo in your `echo` statement, `$Uname` should have been `$uname`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all use a prepared statement: for security reasons you should never trust user inputs, prepared statements do the escaping for you.

Other than that I only see two reasons why nothing is logged:

- error reporting is turned off ( this seems unlikely since you expect to see something in there)
- the query is returning an empty result set and the while loop is skipped

try to print `$uname` or the full query and execute it